# Using key of nested type as index

Tags: typescript

Im not sure if I used goog title, but case is simple.
Lets say I have some nested type :

```
type nested = {
  a : {
    b : any, 
    c : any, 
  },
  b : {
     c : any, 
     d : any, 
  }
}
```

And now my goal is to provide type sefety for function that takes key of `nested` as first argument and then as send argument key of nested value at first argument.

something like this

```
const myFunction(a : keyof nested, b: keyof nested[a]);
```

above doesn't work and throws

```
type a = /*unresolved*/ any
Type 'a' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)
'a' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof a'?(2749)
```

But how then allow second argument to be 'b | c' if first is 'a' and 'c | d' if 'b' ?

Comment: You want `myFunction` to be *generic* as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5550N).  Does that fully address your question, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
const myFunction = <A extends keyof nested>(a : A, b: keyof nested[A]) => {
  // ...
}
```